TPM2 option not visible during the installation
I am attempting to install Ubuntu Server 24.04 using an ISO file. My goal is to set up Full Disk Encryption (FDE) with TPM2 (Trusted Platform Module 2.0). However, I am encountering an issue where the options for Full Disk Encryption and TPM2 are not visible during the installation process.
Here are some details about my current setup:
Secure Boot is enabled on my system.

Could someone provide guidance or resources on how to successfully configure Full Disk Encryption with TPM2 during the installation of Ubuntu Server 24.04? Any step-by-step instructions or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated.
my main doubt is TPM only work with the Desktop image or server image too

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Hi, Did you find an answer to your question?

Hi Joachim, No Actually but my main doubt is TPM only work with the Desktop image or server image too ?
